Difference of Navigation types using Button in React
To navigate to a page on click of a button, I used to do with history.push('/roles/add') but using button as link I never thought of, I'm curious in knowing the difference
To navigate to a page on click of a button,

I used to do with <Button onClick={() => {this.props.history.push('/roles/add')}}>Add</Button> or

I would directly call the component in the onClick event of the button <Button onClick={AddRole}>Add</Button>
but I stumbled upon another way of doing it like <Button as={Link} to={'/roles/add'}> Add </Button>


I was wondering what would be difference like in performance or best practice wise or they have any other difference in functionality level.
And which would be a recommended best practice to navigate to a link on click of a button. Thanks in advance.

By "redirect" do you mean "navigate"?

you are right @Asplund I meant navigate, wrong term, will edit, Thanks

I imagine one key difference is for non-humans reading your page. E.g. in an ideal world, a screen reader could assume a link is for navigation and a button is for an on-page action. But in reality people often just use whichever fits the visual appearance they want.


[...] best practice [...]

The best practice is to use the <Link /> component as the button element <Button as={Link} />.
Assuming you're using react-router, the Link component is rendered as an anchor element (<a />) but when it's clicked by the user it calls preventDefault() to prevent a hard navigation and internally calls useNavigate().navigate() (or some similar History API abstraction).
In effect <Link to="/path" /> is an abstraction of <a onClick={() => navigate("/path")} />.
By not using anchor links (<a />) the user is unable to open the link in a different tab. Furthermore you're hurting accessibility by not supporting assistive technologies. Therefore, you should always use proper tags when possible (not <button onClick={navigate} />).
Another reason not to use JavaScript for navigation is that crawlers such as Google bot cannot discover your pages.


[...] difference like in performance [...]

There's no substantial difference in performance between the two approaches.


[...] difference in functionality level.

For a normal user who only use the mouse to navigate the functionality is the same, however as aforementioned, assistive tools such as a screen reader will without additional markup be unable to recognize the button as a link.
